# How to handle and log Optional or else throw custom exception in java?

Tags: java, exception, logging, option-type

I have a situation where I want to log the success message in case of successful mapping and if error, then not only it throws custom exception, but also log that exception message into a log service.

The code looks like this at the moment

```
public ResponseEntity<Abc> getKontroll(){

  return ogkMaster.performCheck(ors,agk)
                .map(ogka -> {
                    Abc kResponse = Abc.builder()
                            .id(idGeneratorUtil.generateRandomId())                                         
                            .organisationsnummer(ogka.getCompany())
                            .build();

                    logService.auditKreditslagning(ogk.getCompany(), id, "map successful");
            
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(kResponse);
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AgkValidationException("Could not map successfully", 218));
    }
```

What I want to do is something like this in case of exception

```
.orElseThrow(() ->{
Exception e = new AgkValidationException("Could not map", 218));

logService.auditKreditslagning(ogk.getCompany(), id, e.getMessage());

throw e;
}
```

How do I do this if the ogkMaster is an optional value? And ogk.getCompany() also required which is not present in exception case.

Comment: I don't understand the need. `orElseThrow` will be evaluated only if the `Optional` is empty by definition. It's not an exception catcher.

Comment: `orElseThrow` takes a `Supplier`. You have to `return e;` at the end of your code block instead of `throw e;`. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier))